# Separate data from one cell without delimiter to columns

Tags: macos, excel-formula, data-extraction

I have a text string of

Tim Lalatim.lala@excel.com

Is there a way i can separate this cell into

```
1st column - Tim Lala
2nd column - tim.lala@excel.com
```

I appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Using excel this is a bit rough but you can try:

In B2: `=LEFT(A2,SEARCH(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1),A2,LEN(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1)))-1)`

In C2: `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,"")`

[image: example]

This will only work if all other records share the same structure (eg first name matches the email), also won't work if any have a middle name

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Darth Vaderdarth.vader@starwars.com
```

The text before the **@** is 22 characters long *(an even number)*.  That is because:

```
Darth Vader
```

and

```
darth.vader
```

have exactly the same number of letters.  So with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,(FIND("@",A1)-1)/2)
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,(FIND("@",A1)-1)/2+1,99)
```

[image]

This only works if the data before the **@** can be split exactly in half.

Comment: I realize it's just an example, but I'd expect Lord Vader to have an email address like darth.vader@empire.gov or maybe darth.vader@deathstar.mil.gov. Do the people in the Star Wars universe identify with the identifier "Star Wars"?

Comment: @JeremyCaney  Thanks for the comment.......you made me smile............perhaps darth.vader@dearlydeparted.com ??

Comment: thank you so much. this worked on most of the cells! :)